# Clear cache for particular app in iPhone settings

Tags: ios, swift, nscache

I am developing an iOS Application like [Flipkart](https://www.flipkart.com). So, I want to show many images on my dashboard.

Every image was downloading in `URLSession` at every time app is open.
So, I used `NSCache` to save some category of images.
And also used local temp folder to save some images.

My TL asked me to clear all cache images like android app.

How to clear cache in settings?

Comment: There is no option in iPhone for clear cache from Setting for the User, But as a developer you can delete the cache folder from document folder.

Comment: There is no option in iPhone settings to clear cache. Try to keep all images in NSCache and avoid document directory, so that it will be cleared automatically by OS when device running on low memory.

Comment: Unless you have a very specific requirement to make it yourself, you're better off using a ***well maintained*** open-source lib, like https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage